# Obtain distance matrix from scipy `linkage` output

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, linkage

I would like to reconstruct a **condensed distance matrix** from the linkage output when using `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage`.

The input is an `m` by `n` observation matrix. I understand therefore, that the distances are computed internally and then finally output in the linkage table.

Does anybody know of a solution to obtain the condensed distance matrix from the linkage output?

Answer (score 0):

The linkage output clearly does not contain the entire distance matrix. The output is (n-1 x 4), but the entire distance matrix is much larger: n*(n-1)/2.

The contents of the matrix are well described in the Scopus documentation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I was under the impression that the distance matrix can be computed from the output. From your answer I understand that this is not the case?

Comment: Well, for a two point data set, you can do that. Probably even 3 points, if your data is one dimensional and you use Minkowski norms. But you probably have more data than that...